# Flutter: google founding choice

Tags: flutter, gdprconsentform

I'm using [admob_consent](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/admob_consent), doing everything according to the instructions including step "Create respective messages inside Funding Choices for your desired app and publish them".

Deploying on android

after that code, nothing happens

```
_admobConsent.show(forceShow: true);
```

But I'm expecting to get consent dialog

debug console:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue need to select "personalized ads" for EEA and UK users

https://apps.admob.com/v2/pubcontrols/eu-user-consent